# Which dataset could be a good choice to train Environment Sound Classification model for user environment awareness while wearing earbus?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset

Which dataset could be a good choice to train an Environment Sound Classification model for the following use case: use the model in the earbuds/earphones to detect important sound events in the user's environment, so that the medial playback could be dismissed and user could be alerted via a pass-through option (the user hears the environment instead of the media playback).

The output of this model should be binary: either there is a significant sound event in the environment, or there isn't.

Comment: What would be examples of the sound events of interest?

Comment: Car horn for example, dog bark, ambulance, police... all other sounds that you would want to hear when isolated from the environment.